# Insert a Element1 before a Element2

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have two elements and a list. I have to insert the second element before the first element, every time that the first element appears, in the first level of the given list.

Recursive version:

```
(defun INSERT-ELEM (E1 E2 L)
    (cond ((null L)  NIL)
       ((equal E1  (car L))  (cons E2 (INSERT-ELEM  E1 E2 (cdr L))))
       ((equal E2  (car L))  (cons E1 (INSERT-ELEM  E1 E2 (cdr L))))
       (t   (cons (car L) (INSERT-ELEM  E1 E2 (cdr L))))))
```

But something is wrong, it's changing places instead of insert E2 in front of E1.
Could someone help me?

Comment: The line that begins with `((equal E2` is doing the opposite insertion, it puts `E1` before `E2`.

Comment: What @Barmar? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problem.

First, you're only supposed to insert `E2` before `E1`. But the line:

```
   ((equal E2  (car L))  (cons E1 (INSERT-ELEM  E1 E2 (cdr L))))
```

inserts `E1` before `E2` as well. You should remove that.

The second problem is that when you make the recursive call, you're not including the current element in the result. So you're removing all the `E1` elements. Change the recursive call to:

```
(list* e2 (car l) (insert-elem e1 e2 (cdr l)))
```

The working version is:

```
(defun insert-elem (e1 e2 l)
  (cond ((null l)  nil)
        ((equal e1  (car l))  (list* e2 (car l) (insert-elem  e1 e2 (cdr l))))
        (t   (cons (car l) (insert-elem  e1 e2 (cdr l))))))

(insert-elem 'a 'b '(1 2 3 a c b d a b e))
=> (1 2 3 b a c b d b a b e)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar.. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm) variant, for comparison :

```
(defun insert-before (e1 e2 list)
  (loop
    for e in list
    when (equalp e e1)
      collect e2
    collect e))

(insert-before 1 0 '(5 4 1 2 1 3 5 1 1 2 3 5 7))
=> (5 4 0 1 2 0 1 3 5 0 1 0 1 2 3 5 7)
```

The [`MAPCAN`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) variant, for fun:

```
(defun insert-before (e1 e2 list)
  (mapcan (lambda (e)
            (if (equalp e e1)
              (list e2 e1)
              (list e)))
          list))
```